# Query any sample dataset from a newly created BigQuery project

Tags: api, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

Is there any way to query sample datasets as here

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/sample-tables

from a newly created Project using my application in GAE.Or do i need link the sample dataset to the newly created project in Big Query.If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access BigQuery's publicdata:samples tables from any Google Developer project (that has the BigQuery API activated).

When building App Engine applications that access the BigQuery API, there are several authorization choices, which you can read about here:

Web Server Auth flow:
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization#web-server-applications

App Engine Service Account Auth flow:
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization#service-accounts-appengine

There's another great sample (Python) here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/source/browse/samples/python/appengine-bq-join/